# Android: ScrollView doesn't work with TableLayout

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

I try to use ScrollView and a TableLayout inside of ScrollView like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Input text: " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/weightEditText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

But it doesn't work. Scroll bars doesn't display if even my content is too large. Does anyone have any suggestions why it works like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the scrollview layout_height to match_parent like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >
```

When you use wrap_content your scrollview will just grow larger even when the screen ends, but when using match_parent your scrollview will fit the screen and when the content of the scrollview overflows it will show scrollbars.

Rolf